# Vue navigation guard runs before localStorage on hard refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

So I'm trying to check permissions for the user before they can access a route. I've tried to use `route.beforeEach` and `route.beforeResolve`. It works perfectly if the localStorage in the tab has been loaded, but if I try to access the route in the new tab it returns to 404 which mean that the user don't have the permission. The work flow is like this:

Current:

1. new tab on browser
2. http://url/route
3. returns 404
4. navigate from button to http://url/route
5. success navigate to the route page

Expected:

1. new tab on browser
2. http://url/route
3. success navigate to the route page if the user has permission

Here is the code:

```
router.beforeEach((to: any, from: any, next: any) => {
  let permission: any = localStorage.getItem(`${process.env.NODE_ENV}_user_role_permission`);
  permission = permission ? JSON.parse(permission) : [];
  console.log(permission);
  if (!(to.meta.permission === permission)) {
    next("/not-found");
    return;
  }
  next();
});
```

The problem is that, when I try to access it on the new tab, the `console.log(permission)` will return null, but when I access it from that 404 page, I'll be able to navigate. Is it possible that the router runs before localStorage?

Comment: No. But it is possible that you're writing to localStorage after this runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem is that I call my api to load the permission and save it to the localStorage, the flow is like this:

1. check if the user has been logged in
2. if yes, then call api to load the localstorage
3. if not, then redirect to the login page